# Scrolling to top of my page slowly near the end of the scrolling process

Tags: jquery

I succeed scrolling to top of my page using the following jQuery script:

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

But I would like to have the scrolling to go slower near the end of the scrolling process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.animate( properties [, duration] [, easing] [, complete] )
```

As you can see animate has an easing option, that is what you are looking for.

Please refer to the jQuery API: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: the same documentation you specified stated this: `The remaining parameter of .animate() is a string naming an easing function to use. An easing function specifies the speed at which the animation progresses at different points within the animation. The only easing implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing, and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the ` so by default it's actually already `swing`, which slows down nearing the end